# How to retrieve data from mongoose and use it in every page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm create a simple website where user have to register in it and subscribe to some challenge that is activated. I'm using passport to make the registration and the login form and save the user email and password into my DB. The problem is when I try to use the user email for example in another page.
Once a user have done the login my app redirect him to the profile page and there I can retrieve the data from the database, but when I try to use the data in another page I can't.
Someone know how to fix this?

my passport file

```
  passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will         override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
    function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // if no user is found, return the message
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!user.validPassword(password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, user);
        });

    }));
```

here is my redirect page

```
  app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

    // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
    res.render('login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
});

// process the login form
// app.post('/login', do all our passport stuff here);
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/partecipant', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));
```

my partecipant page, and here i can retrieve the data using this variable

```
        <p>id: <%= user.id %></p>


        <p>email:<%= user.local.email %></p>

        <p>password: <%= user.local.password %></p>
```

here is another page where i try to use the same variables as used in the partecipant page but It doesn't work

```
 <section id="wrapPartecipant1">
            <p>email:<%= user.local.email %></p>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you authenticate a user with Passport, the user should be stored in `req.user`.

```
app.get('/particepant', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user);
});
```

What you can do is then create a [local variable that is accessible to all views](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals). You would set this variable in a middleware.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
});

app.get('/particepant', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user);
});

// and other routes
```